# nuxt js build locally, and run on server of the production

Tags: nuxt.js

I build the project of nuxt js locally, i.e., `npm run build`, and push the project with .nuxt folder, but not the folder of node_modules. 
Then run the command of `npm run start`, failed.

The output info: 
sh: nuxt: command not found

Why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`npm run start` will run the script from `package.json`:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "nuxt start",
    ...
}
```

it's an alias to run `node_modules/nuxt/bin/nuxt start`

so the `node_modules/` folder is mandatory.